# Is there a way to hide the axis locking guide?

Tags: 3d-view, transforms

Whenever we axis lock transformations, the x/y/z guideline appears, and it's a bit intrusive for me when translating and snapping thin objects. Can it be hidden somehow?

Comment: No i don't think they can be hidden at the moment, though you can change their colors in the themes to something less intrusive, though they will remain visible still.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's disappointing. D': Thanks!

Comment: @Helixfate could you add a screenshot of what you mean?